# Counting question on permutation matrices with rotation and imprinting

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

Please read [question of distinct permutation matrices with rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151421/how-many-non-isomorphic-permutation-selections-are-on-an-arbitrary-n-x-n-square) at first, then new counting questions are below:

1. For a distinct $N\times N$ zero-symmetry permutation matrix, we could rotate it 3 times and imprint all 4 images into a single canvas. Then there would be at most $4\times N$ cells selected in the final **imprinted** matrix. I called such matrix is Dispersed. How many Dispersed matrices for $N\times N$ permutation matrices?
2. In the set of above **imprinted** matrices, some are same. Then how many distinct **imprinted** matrices?

Some examples of imprinted images for $4\times 4$ matrices (Please only look at row 2,3,5 and 6 which are zero-symmetry matrices. The images in left side are original, and in right side are **imprinted** ones. In special, images in row 5 and 6 are Dispersed):

[image]

Comment: Is this question really so hard?